# SPARQL and linked data: Getting the attribute of an external property

Tags: sparql, linked-data, turtle-rdf

I think I'm having a logical problem that might be connected to the understanding of the linked data structure, but it could also just be a SPARQL issue.

I inserted the following extract of a turtle-code to my triple store. I create an observation. And one of the properties (SPACE) I try to take from another server and also its value (X01).

```
<http://myserver/mydataset/observation/B> a cube:Observation ;
   <https://otherserver/property/SPACE> <https://otherserver/code/X01> .
```

Now, generally I managed to insert the property to my triple store. But I cannot access the attributes of that property (that I have not defined from my side, but I thought that it would be possible to access them in a linked way?). Thus the following partial pseudo-code, where the schema:name of that property is supposed to be extracted does not work:

```
SELECT ?obs ?place
WHERE {
  <http://myserver/mydataset> a cube:Cube;
             cube:observationSet/cube:observation ?obs. 
   ?obs <https://otherserver/property/SPACE>/<https://schema.org/name> ?place .
}
```

However, the code works without the schema:name - it then just shows the property-link that I defined.

Why does he not give me the schema:name that is defined in the other server? Do I have to specify all attributes from my side as well?

Comment: because the triple store aka SPARQL endpoint does not automatically gets the data loaded into another triple store on another server. How should this work? Look at SPARQL federated querying if you want to access external SPARQL endpoints: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-federated-query/

Comment: Thank you very much @UninformedUser ! This solved it indeed! Do you want to write it as answer, so I can accept it?